# Jackson JsonParser fails reading an array in Json

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a Json Structure something like this

```
{
"name" : "abcd",
"details" : [{"city":"string", "zipcode":"integer"}],

"name" : "qwert",
"details" : [{"address":"long", "state":"string"}]
}
```

And my java code looks like below

```
public class JsonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, IOException {

        JsonFactory jf = new JsonFactory(); 
        JsonParser jp = jf.createParser(new File("C:\\sample.json"));

        while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT)
        {
            String jsonField = jp.getCurrentName();

            if ("name".equalsIgnoreCase(jsonField))
            {
                jp.nextToken();
                System.out.println(jp.getText());
            }

            if ("details".equalsIgnoreCase(jsonField))
            {
                jp.nextToken();
                while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY)
                {
                    jp.nextToken();
                    String field = jp.getText();
                    System.out.println(field);
                }
            }
        }           
    }

}
```

All am trying to do is parse the whole json token by token and get the text. But the line `while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT)` fails when it encounters a '}' in the array. Am just stuck here since yesterday and experimenting with several other tricks but nothing works out. Do we have another way doing this? Is my JSON structure looks okay? Please tell me where am going wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use `new ObjectMapper().readTree(yourFile)`?

Comment: @fge can you please give me some example on using readTree()? I have even tried it but was not sure of how to use it. Sorry am just new to jackson. :(

Comment: A) the JSON you posted isn't related to the code you've posted. B) Why are you attempting to manually parse your JSON as a stream? C) You're not even close to correctly doing so; you aren't accounting for the array in any way. D) See:  https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind for a tutorial in their readme on how to use Jackson.

Comment: @BrianRoach as you can see I have duplicate keys in my JSON. So I think I cannot use POJO. Thats why am manually parsing it. For one whole iteration of the JSON I need a list of all "name" fields. And in other iteration I want all "details". I hope you got my point here. Is there any other way you think I can restructure my JSON and parse it?? Sorry for not updating my code when I was posting the question. Thanks for pointing my mistakes out.

Comment: That's not legal JSON.  You can't have two keys by the same name in a single object.  (As others have said, use an array.  JSON is pretty logical, and where it makes sense to use an array you can use an array.)

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

> [Doe]s my JSON structure look[s] okay?

Yes and no. while your JSON is legal, you are going to have a problem because of duplicate keys:

```
{
    "name": "xxx",
    "name": "yyy"
}
```

The behaviour of a JSON parser in this event is unpredictable, [even RFC 7159 says so](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-4) (yes, RFC 4627 has been superseded). Unfortunately, duplicate keys are *still* not forbidden.

So, it is legal, but not sane. Use an array instead:

```
[ { "name": "xxx", "details": "whatever" }, "etc" ]
```

This aside, reading JSON with Jackson is done as this:

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
final JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(yourFileHere);
```

You can then use the full power of [`JsonNode`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html).

Comment: { "student":[{"name" : "abcd", "details" : [{"city":"string", "zipcode":"integer"}]},
   {"name" : "qwert", "details" : [{"address":"long", "state":"string"}]}]
}

you mean something like this right?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have fields with the same name in a json, well you can but it could not be parsed as in your case.

I assume you have an `array of users` with `name` and `details` fileds for each user.

Here is a candidate Java class corresponding to your `User class`:

```
public class TestUser implements Serializable {
    String name;
    List<Map<String, String>> details = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    TestUser() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Map<String, String>> getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(List<Map<String, String>> details) {
        this.details = details;
    }
}
```

with reverse engineering lets see how is a list of users are de-serialized;

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<TestUser> testUsers = new ArrayList<TestUser>();

    TestUser testUser1 = new TestUser();
    testUser1.name = "abcd";
    HashMap<String, String> detailsHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    detailsHashMap.put("city", "string");
    detailsHashMap.put("zipcode", "integer");
    testUser1.details.add(detailsHashMap);
    testUsers.add(testUser1);

    TestUser testUser2 = new TestUser();
    testUser2.name = "qwert";
    detailsHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    detailsHashMap.put("address", "long");
    detailsHashMap.put("state", "string");
    testUser2.details.add(detailsHashMap);
    testUsers.add(testUser2);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(testUsers));

}
```

and the outcome of the users list is:

```
[ {
  "name" : "abcd",
  "details" : [ {
    "zipcode" : "integer",
    "city" : "string"
  } ]
}, {
  "name" : "qwert",
  "details" : [ {
    "address" : "long",
    "state" : "string"
  } ]
} ]
```

As you can see it is different from your JSON string.

**UPDATE**
If you want to hold names and details in two separate containers...;

```
public static class Container {
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    Map<String, String> details = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public Container() {
    }

    public List<String> getNames() {
        return names;
    }

    public void setNames(List<String> names) {
        this.names = names;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(Map<String, String> details) {
        this.details = details;
    }
}

....
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Container container = new Container();
    container.names.add("abcd");
    container.names.add("qwert");
    container.details.put("city", "string");
    container.details.put("zipcode", "integer");
    container.details.put("address", "long");
    container.details.put("state", "string");

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(container));
}
```

and the outcome JSON is;

```
{
  "names" : [ "abcd", "qwert" ],
  "details" : {
    "address" : "long",
    "zipcode" : "integer",
    "state" : "string",
    "city" : "string"
  }
}
```

Comment: great explanation hevi... thanks :)
but I have only one problem in this. When serializing this I would like to have only all name fields in a list and details in a map. Will you please help posting few lines of code on how to deserialize this?

Comment: I couldn't really get what you mean. My best guess is that you want to store all the names and details in separate collections, well this doesn't really make sense to me but, I update my answer accordingly.